# How to avoid sibling component rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to know if it's possible to avoid a sibling component rerendering when it's data hasn't changed.
I guess it's probably because of the way i have it structure so let me clarify what i have today.
I have a Smart component which has access to a state similar to this:

```
showcaseState = {
    products: {
        1: {
            name: "Ball"
        },
        2: {
            name: "Puzzle"
        }
    },
    cart: [2]
}
```

And this Smart component renders two Dumb Components. The first one (ProductsList component) receives the list of products, and the second one (Cart component) gets a list that only contains the products that match the index(es) inside the cart property.
Whenever i click one product inside the ProductsList component, it fires an action that adds that product index to the cart, so the Cart component gets rerendered.

The thing is, the ProductsList is also getting rerendered, even though it's data didn't change at all. My guess is that it's happening because the Main Component rerenders. How do i avoid this? Should i make the ProductList component Smart, give it access to the products state and remove products from the Main component?

I'm a little bit lost regarding which is the best way to achieve this.

EDIT

The rendering of the Smart components is something like this

```
let { products, cart } = this.props.app
let cartProds = cart.map(prodId => { return products[prodId] })

<div>
    <ProductsList prods={products} />
</div>
<div>
    <Cart prods={cartProds} />
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some snippets of where you're rendering the Cart and ProductList components, along with the properties you're passing down to them.

Comment: Take a look at [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (and `shouldComponentUpdate()` in general).

Comment: How do you change the product list? It could be because reference to the list is changed. to Overcome this you will need either to implement shouldComponentUpdate or maintain reference to the list if it not changed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this, I ended up using redux to manage the app state, and separating the things each component needed.